# How to speed up process running inside Writer in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch process. `Reader` will read data from database and `Writer` will send `POST` request and also update the database. I am using `Partitioner` and the `GridSize` is 100. The issue is inside `Writer` the process is taking some time. There are 50 million records in the database. But because of the slowness in the `Writer` process this is taking days to finish. If I commented out that Writer process and run, then it will finish the Batch process by within 4 hours. So the slowness is because of the process inside `Writer`.

```
public class DataWriter implements ItemWriter<Sample> {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired        
    private RestTemplate rst;

    public DataWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void write(List<? extends Sample> samples) {
        samples.forEach(this::run);
    }

    private void run(Sample sample) {
        boolean value = sendRequest();
        jdbc.update("UPDATE_QUERY", value, sample.getId());
    }

    private boolean sendRequest() {
        ResponseEntity<String> res = rst.postForEntity("URL", getRequestData(), String.class);
        return res.getStatusCode().value() == 200;
    }
}
```

How to make this fast? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No the slowness is not in the writer, it is in the database set up.   I assume this table you are inserting into has constraints?   If so you need to make sure there is an exact matching index for each table constraint.    i.e  If you have a table constraint that combines say three columns you need a single index that combines all three of those columns

Also need to check with your DBA on any other details logic/scripts/PLSQL/triggers that maybe executing on events on that table.

Alternatively you can create a temp table on the job start and insert into that.  Then at the job end run a table to table copy (when not exists) to the intended table.   Doing a table to table copy inside the database is MUCH faster.